# Mongo db query on array list

Tags: java, mongodb

Hello I am using mongo java 3.0 driver and trying to query the following. I have a entity class and inside that a list of names. My problem is to query on the list of names. My code is

```
if(e != null) {
    for(int i = 0; i < e.getName().size(); i++) {
        Document nameDocument = new Document();
        nameDocument.append("fName", e.getName().get(i).getfName());
        nameDocument.append("lName", e.getName().get(i).getlName());
        nameDocument.append("dob", e.getName().get(i).getDob());
        nameDocument.append("address", e.getName().get(i).getAddress());

        nameDocumentList.add(nameDocument);
    }
}

mongoCollection = mongoDatabase.getCollection("entity");
Document entityDocument = new Document();

entityDocument.append("entityId", e.getEntityId());
entityDocument.append("entityType", e.getEntityType());
entityDocument.append("nameIdentity", nameDocumentList);

mongoCollection.insertOne(entityDocument);
```

and my query is:

```
FindIterable<Document> iterable = mongoDatabase.getCollection("entity")
    .find(new Document("nameIdentity.fName", "Mujahid")
    .append("nameIdentity.lName", "ali"));

iterable.forEach(new Block<Document>() {
    @Override
    public void apply(final Document document)
    {
        System.out.println(document);
    }
});
```

This is working if I print the whole document, but this is not working if I extract only the embedded document list's field

```
qname1 = document.getString("nameIdentity.fName").toString();
qname2 = document.getString("nameIdentity.lName").toString();
```

Any suggestions where am i going wrong?

Comment: Can you add the output of your full document print